# find column name in sql query

Tags: sql, user-interface, find

I would like to use the GUI to find q column name in my sql query which has more than 300 columns

For example: I want to use GUI provided by SQL to find all the column names starting with VENDOR and hi-light them in order to make my operation easier..

**I just want to use GUI**

P.S: No query suggestions please, I am already aware of them (using like and all)

Comment: You need a complete SQL grammar...

Answer (score -1):

In MSQL Studio, use the Query Designer (Design Query In Editor...), paste your SQL, then use the name column in criteria pane to copy and paste in excel